# why the django custom middleware not able to catch the exception?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

I have written a custom django middleware to do retries and catch exception if there is any connection related issues between two servers. Below is the code snippet.

```
from requests.adapters import Retry, RetryError, HTTPAdapter, MaxRetryError, ConnectTimeoutError, ProtocolError, ResponseError
from requests.sessions import Session
from django.http import HttpResponseServerError


class RetryCal:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    @staticmethod
    def process_request(request):
        try:
            session = Session()
            retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=2, status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504])
            session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
            request.retry_session = session

        except Exception as e:
            raise e

    def __call__(self, request):
        RetryCal.process_request(request)
        try:
            response = self.get_response(request)
            return response

        except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:
            raise ConnectionError(err, request)

        except MaxRetryError as e:
            if isinstance(e.reson, ConnectTimeoutError):
                return HttpResponseServerError("Connection timeout error...")
            if isinstance(e.reson, ResponseError):
                raise RetryError(e, request=request)

            raise ConnectionError(e, request)
```

Below is the placement of the custom middleware

```
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

# custom retry middleware.
'integ.api_retry_custom_middleware.RetryCal',
```

belo this custom middleware I do have other default one's as well.

The problem is I am not sure if this is working. I have a access token, In that I added some garbage characters and tried to hit my endpoints. I did see an exception as seen below

```
Internal Server Error: /api/acct/
[24/Jan/2024 14:23:39] "GET /api/acct/ HTTP/1.1" 500 5348
```

But I can see this error even if I comment out my custom middleware. My purpose is to create the custom middleware and if there is any API request from any django App the request should go first through the custom middleware. That is my thought. But I am not sure if the middleware is working. Or may be the placement if the custom middleware is not proper. I have seen old posts from stackoverflow, but they are not related to mine issue. I have been working with django for a while now, but written the custom middleware for the first time.Please suggest.